# Spacing in Nav Menu

Tags: css, navigation, margin, padding

I have a small space in my main navigation menu at:

http://ranchocordovaeventscenter.com/

I can't seem to find any css that is causing it to do this.

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance,

Matt

Comment: Where is the space? Take a screenshot and circle it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that each anchor tag `<a>` inside the `<li>` element have borders in both sides...

To solve this, add `border-right-width` here:

```
.main-navigation li a {
    border-right-width: 1px solid #F9B233;
}
```

and remove the following property in the above selector:

```
 border-width: 1px solid #F9B233;
```

To remove the right border of the last element you can do this:

```
.main-navigation li:last-child a
{
    border-right-width: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your setting the list elements to inline-block. It's creating spaces between each element as if it's text ( words should have spaces between them, it makes sense if you think about it ).

```
.nav-menu {
  font-size: 0;
}
```

Just make sure you reset the font-size on the children or else they will inherit this size and be illegible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the space you are talking about, but something similar happened to me earlier.

[CSS Box Model Puzzle - I must be missing something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14096165/css-box-model-puzzle-i-must-be-missing-something)

The key is is the following piece of css code:

```
box-sizing: border-box; /* needs prefixes for webkit/moz */
```

Try including this css property for the container divs you may have.

Hope this helps!